# React Native receive remote push notification only if app is in background

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am using [react-native-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) in my react-native app to receive the remote push notifications. Everything is working fine I am getting all notifications when the app is either in foreground or background.

But I want the notifications to show only when the app is in the background. **If the app is in the foreground it should not show the notification.**

Any help will be really appreciated.

My manifest file contains the following code:

```
  <meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
  <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name" android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
  <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description" android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
  <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
  <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@android:color/white"/>

  <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
  <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
  <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want notifications in background then you should send only data payload messages from server. If notification payload contains **notification key** then android os automatically show those notifications.So better use only data payload in notification content.

Refer this link about fcm messages:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I can't modify the payloads because I am receiving the push notification from third party service (Rocket.chat).

Comment: I can control this in ios with the help of `#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>`. I am looking for something similar I can do in manifest or Gradle files.

Comment: that is not possible with manifest or gradle file, If you want to control notification you have to do it in payload